# How do I set up a login script, to run xrandr?

Tags: xrandr, x-server

I am using 3 monitors, with the 2 side ones being rotated.

I was not able to sucesfully configure `xorg.conf` to rotate the 2 monitors, but I found a `xrandr` command that I can use after my login manager has been started:

```
xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --rotate right --left-of DisplayPort-0
xrandr --output DisplayPort-2 --rotate left --right-of DisplayPort-0
```

currently, I am running these commands manually after login.

Where should I put these, so that my monitors are rotated on login.
Also, can I perhaps do it globally? So that when I log in as other user, monitors are rotated.
Or does every user need a user script to do this after login ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using a 2 screens layout which is a bit similar to yours, mine is a regular screen on the right and a portrait-oriented one on the left. With my setup I have X working perfectly on my 2 screens.

Here's my proposition for your own case (hard to test as I don't have the same screens and don't have 3 screens) but that should be enough for you to get a working X setup.

Put the following files in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

```
30-screen-dport0.conf
30-screen-dport1.conf
30-screen-dport2.conf
```

with the following content :

#### 30-screen-dportcenter.conf

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier   "DisplayPort-0"
  Option       "Primary" "true"
  Option       "PreferredMode"   "3840x2160" # Adapt this if you resolution is not the same
  Option       "Position"        "1200 0" 
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier   "DPC"
  Device       "nVidia" # here you choose your driver
  Monitor      "DisplayPort-0"
EndSection
```

#### 30-screen-dportleft.conf

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier   "DisplayPort-1 "
  Option       "LeftOf" "DisplayPort-0"
  Option       "Rotate" "left" 
  Option       "PreferredMode"   "1920x1200"
  Option       "Position"        "0 0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier   "DPL"
  Device       "nVidia"
  Monitor      "DisplayPort-1"
EndSection
```

#### 30-screen-dportright.conf

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier   "DisplayPort-2"
  Option       "RightOf" "DisplayPort-0"
  Option       "Rotate" "right" 
  Option       "PreferredMode"   "1920x1200"
  Option       "Position"        "5040 0" # 1200 + 3840
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier   "DPR"
  Device       "nVidia"
  Monitor      "DisplayPort-2"
EndSection
```

#### 90-serverlayout.conf

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier   "Main"
    Screen       0 "DPL"
    Screen       1 "DPC"
    Screen       2 "DPR
EndSection
```

---

The coordinates of the Xserver works the following way

```
 0                 X
+ -----------------> X-axis 
|0
|
|
|
|
| 
| Y
V Y-axis
```

The nVidia identifier is a reference to a video card defined in a file called

#### 20-nvidia.conf

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "nVidia"
  Driver      "nouveau"
  Option      "AccelMethod"  "sna"
  Option      "GLXVBlank"    "true"
  # Need to flag this as only referring to one output on the card
  Screen      0

EndSection
```

Comment: I am lost in your config. How many `Section "Monitor"` do you have ?

Comment: @400theCat, for my case, there are 2, one per file. In your case you should have 3, one per file as well. I'll try to edit to make it more clear, I tried to explain what I use and what I think you should use, but I'll just keep the second part.

Comment: And BTW, you don't need to put those in different files - different files are very helpful for configurations that are part of a package, but for manual configurations a single file is often simpler. But of course you *can* put them in different files, if you prefer.

Comment: @400theCat, any issue still preventing you from using this ?

Comment: @Pierre-Alain TORET - thanks for checking. Unfortunately, I was not able to make this work. Here is my complete `xorg.conf`, in case you want to have a look: https://pastebin.com/tnfMpZrF

Comment: @400theCat do you have logs from X ? What is the actual layout you get with the configuration you provide. What are the resolutions of your screen ? I specified some in my config snippets, but you don't have any in your xorg.conf.

Comment: @Pierre-Alain TORET - my main monitor is  `3840x2160`, and the two side monitors are `1920x1200`. I have seen you include the resolution in `xorg.conf`, but is it necessary for the rotation ? My resolution works OK as it is, all I need is to rotate th two side monitors.

Comment: @400theCat, the thing is not only the rotation but also the position of the screens on the global server layout. I'll try to update the config accordingly

Comment: @400theCat, I've updated, please try with this config exactly (and the one you have for the video card)

Answer (score 3):

I use a user-land systemd service (full path = `$HOME/.config/systemd/user/set-display.service`) to handle a similar situation on my QEMU VMs that use XFCE and do not automatically fill the screen (cut short due to conky):

```
[Unit]
Description=Set Display Resolution

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xrandr --output Virtual-0 --mode 1499x996

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I use the sleep command to make sure that the DE is fully loaded; my VMs on SSDs were always fine with 5 seconds or less, the HDD ones sometimes needed more. Just create a script that runs both of your xrandr commands, substitute it on the **ExecStart=** (something like `ExecStart=/path/to/your/script`), then enable it (`systemctl --user enable set-display`).

UPDATE: testing as system service on Debian Buster did not work, even when running the service manually after logging in (tried as root and normal user).

Comment: thank you, but I am not using systemd, so this solution will not work for me.

Comment: OK. What OS are you running? Does it have a directory called `/etc/xdg/autostart`?

Comment: I am running Debian Buster (with SysVinit as init). I have directory `/etc/xdg/`, so I guess I can create `autostart`.

Comment: @MartinVegter: how do you start X server? Are you using `startx` or use some login manager such as XDM?

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk - I am using `slim` login manager.

Comment: @MartinVegter: see my answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560892/72304

Answer (score 2):

You have to put these two lines in one of the files executed by your
login manager or window manager when they start.  Which file would
that be exactly depends on what login manager and window manager you
use and your system local setup.

For example, if you use `slim` login manager you should put startup
commands in the file specified by `login_cmd` in the config. On Debian
for example:

```
$ grep '^login_cmd ' /etc/slim.conf
login_cmd           exec /bin/bash -login /etc/X11/Xsession %session
```

But on Slackware:

```
$ grep '^login_cmd ' /etc/slim.conf
login_cmd           exec /bin/bash -login ~/.xinitrc %session
```

On Debian, I think the best place would be a new file created in
/etc/X11/Xsession.d, say `90xrandr` with the following contents:

```
xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --rotate right --left-of DisplayPort-0
xrandr --output DisplayPort-2 --rotate left --right-of DisplayPort-0
```

You don't have make it executable or add a shebang as it would be
sourced by `/etc/X11/Xsession`:

```
# use run-parts to source every file in the session directory; we source
# instead of executing so that the variables and functions defined above
# are available to the scripts, and so that they can pass variables to each
# other
SESSIONFILES=$(run-parts --list $SYSSESSIONDIR)
if [ -n "$SESSIONFILES" ]; then
  set +e
  for SESSIONFILE in $SESSIONFILES; do
    . $SESSIONFILE
  done
  set -e
fi
```

Also notice that `login_cmd` is run *after* user logs in so you would
have to use `slim` in the default monitor setup each time it starts.

Comment: that works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From command line (if you are using nano otherwise replace with vim)

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/rotate-screen-1.desktop
```

Then paste the following and save:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Xrandr Screen 1 Rotation
Icon=preferences-desktop-screensaver
Exec=xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --rotate right --left-of DisplayPort-0
Terminal=false
OnlyShowIn=LXDE;OPENBOX;GNOME;KDE;
Categories=System;Security;Utility;
StartupNotify=false
X-KDE-autostart-after=panel
X-OPENBOX-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Then the same for the second screen

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/rotate-screen-2.desktop
```

Then paste the following and save:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Xrandr Screen 2 Rotation
Icon=preferences-desktop-screensaver
Exec=xrandr --output DisplayPort-2 --rotate left --right-of DisplayPort-0
Terminal=false
OnlyShowIn=LXDE;OPENBOX;GNOME;KDE;
Categories=System;Security;Utility;
StartupNotify=false
X-KDE-autostart-after=panel
X-OPENBOX-Autostart-enabled=true
```

After reboot the screen should rotate automatically